# Is approval-based sign-ups possible with Slack?

Tags: slack-api, slack

Normally, I invite new members via. email, that I get from them individually.

Let's say I want to campaign publicly for volunteers to join our community, then what is the best approaches with various level of control?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

Comment: Woops, sorry! Should I remove my post or du something else?

Comment: Karl, no problem. You can remove the post if you want to. Or you can leave it and see if anyone responds, or if it is closed. But it would be better to post in a community which specialises in this sort of thing.

Comment: I'll answer it no problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible out-of-the-box,  but you can develop a custom website, where people can apply for your Slack and enter the name and email address.

You can then forward their request for you to approve (e.g. a page with a table of all open requests where each can be approved or denied or an automatically generated email to you etc).

Finally you can auto-invite every approved user with his email address. The Slack API has an undocumented API function that allows that. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30955818/slack-api-team-invitation/36114710#36114710) for my post about that method.

I have done a similar website for inviting people from a gaming community ([Eve Online](https://www.eveonline.com/)), where they have to first authenticate themselves with their game login before getting an invite to our Slack. It works pretty well. I made this website with PHP, but basically every server based script language will work.