# SLACK: Is it possible to invite users to a workspace via api?

Tags: slack, slack-api

I have created a web app in python and when a user completes sign up on that application I would like to send them an invite to the slack workspace automatically. I have just started to look at slack API but I can't seem to find it. Is it not possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Slack API team invitation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30955818/slack-api-team-invitation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an undocumented method in the Slack API that does it.

https://github.com/ErikKalkoken/slackApiDoc
Specfically for invite https://github.com/ErikKalkoken/slackApiDoc/blob/master/users.admin.invite.md

Check that out for undocumented slackApi calls.

Comment: This is now no longer valid as slack has removed ability to generate legacy tokens. I'm not sure if this can be done anymore? 'admin.users.invite' appears to only be for 'enterprise grid' and not free/plus slack workspaces. Anybody know any other methods?

Answer (score 4):

Sadly, this is now only possible for paid Slack workspaces due to removel of legacy test tokens - see https://api.slack.com/changelog/2020-02-legacy-test-token-creation-to-retire

To do this for paid accounts, use the [admin.users.invite method](https://api.slack.com/methods/admin.users.invite).