# Inviting new members to workspace

Tags: api, slack, slack-api

I'm new to Slack, using a free plan, and although I have no issue creating/populating channels/conversations using the Web API I cannot find a method to initiate invitation to new members.

I found many documentation using a deprecated method (https://slack.com/api/users.admin.invite) but this requires to add  `client` scope to my App. This scope being legacy, I'm not able to add it to my App.

The only method I could find that seems to be performing what I need is `admin.users.invite` which is only available for Enterprise Grid customers.

Has anybody been able to work around that? Is thre any modern way to invite a new members using the API?

Thank for your help.

--
Stephan

Comment: This question has been asked and answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30955818/slack-api-team-invitation/36114710  Best of luck!

Comment: Yes, thank you, I saw that but as mentioned in my original question this method is deprecated hence my question about a more modern one.