# Is there a way I can invite users to my slack workspace through the slack API for non-enterprise slack grid?

Tags: slack, slack-api

I understand that the `admin.users.invite` API method described [here](https://api.slack.com/methods/admin.users.invite) is **ONLY** available to members of the enterprise slack grid due to the admin OAuth scope associated with it. Is there an API method for non-enterprise slack grid members that allows me to invite users to my workspace?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Slack API team invitation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30955818/slack-api-team-invitation)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the Slack API returns the `Apps with this feature are only available to Enterprise customers.` error when a non-admin member tries to add admin scopes to their app. To solve the problem you can either request to be made an admin or request an admin member to create the app for you. The API method is **NOT** available outside the Enterprise Slack Grid.